# Modifying data in non-DOM elements in D3?

Tags: d3.js

I am using thehierarchical layout sample from the `D3` site that hides/shows child nodes. I load the data from json and only show some of the elements at start (just like in the demo).

**What I want to achieve is this**:

When a user does a specific action, I want to add data to some of the non-"visible" (and technically **inexistent** in the DOM) nodes. So that, when those nodes eventually get created in the DOM by D3 (by means on a user clicking on their parent node), that extra data is available to me in the usual way.

Does `D3` support doing something like that?

Comment: No. It sounds like you could store the data in the "traditional" way though.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff I 've spend a good part of the day assuming it was possible and in the end I was "hmm, perhaps it 's not supported this way?" :) Please add it as an answer so that I can accept and close this.

Comment: Why not just bind it to a javascript object, which later is used to populate the divs.

Comment: @Incodeveritas That 's what I 'm doing now, but if there was a D3 way, I 'd prefer to use it instead

Comment: Have you tried creating a selector and entering the data to it, then appending later? Say to the parent div

Comment: @Incodeveritas The data will be lost once D3 destroys the object when the user hides the node. So it 's not robust and I keep the state separately and apply the data changes on `update`.

Comment: @rollingBalls You shouldn't be destroying your data object selector. Use .exit().remove() to delete unneeded nodes but maintain constancy with your data selector object.

Comment: @Incodeveritas I am using this demo: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 In its update function it does `.exit()....remove();` I see the elements getting destroying on collapse in the inspector console.

Comment: Ah yes with D3.layout.tree as your selector you will end up with this outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind data only to DOM nodes in D3. From your description it sounds like you don't need DOM nodes though, you can simply add the data to an array and then later (when you want to create the DOM nodes) use D3's usual `.data()` mechanism.